# Too many significant dummy variables in fixed-effect panel model

Tags: categorical-data, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am doing panel analysis of state drug policies. My data set includes 50 states and ten time points. I am using one-way state fixed-effect models, controlling for heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation using Stata [xtscc](http://econpapers.repec.org/software/bocbocode/s456787.htm) command.

In one of the models, 48 of the state dummy variables are significant. Is this a problem? My model has ten IVs, five of which are significant in this model with an R-squared of .80.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not a problem.

If you have an intercept term in your model, one of the state dummies will be dropped, and the others then give the state means relative to the omitted state. In this case, statistically significant state dummies just mean that those states have means that are statistically significantly different from the omitted state. I can't see how this would be a problem.

If you instead have dropped your intercept term, and therefore can include dummies for all states, the state dummies simply capture the mean for each state. In this case, statistically significant dummies just mean that those states have means that are statistically significantly different from zero. I can't see how this would be a problem, either.

Comment: An alternate way to parameterize the state dummies would be "sum-to-zero" contrasts. Then the intercept corresponds to the average state, and the state coefficients give you the difference between that state's baseline level and the average state's baseline.  This is less arbitrary and maybe more interpretable than choosing one state as the "reference" (unless there really is one state that'd you like to treat as the reference).

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. In cases where you want to interpret the state fixed effects, I agree that this might be the natural approach.